# Change the link text when click on that is not working correct

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here When i click on the link get the appropriate **id** but change the status to all posts. Not in selected item

here **html** code

```
<div th:each="p : ${posts}">
<div id="para">
<a style="float: right;" href="#" class="decision"
th:text="${p.approved}">Approve</a> 
<input type="hidden" class="pid"  th:value="*{p.id}" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

when i click approve link  get the id value is correct. but change status effect all other posts

Here is **script**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.decision').click(function(e) {
$.ajax({

type : 'POST',
dataType : 'json',
url : '/RealEstate/ChangeStatus.html',
data : ({

pid :$(this).siblings('.pid').val()
}),
success : function(response) {
alert(response);
$('.decision').html(response);
/* $('.decision').text(response); */
},
error : function() {
alert('Error while request..');
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

and the **controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/ChangeStatus.html")
@ResponseBody
public String approvDisapprove(@RequestParam("pid") String pid) {
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = null;
Property property = propertyDAO.findById(Integer.parseInt(pid));
if (property.getApproved() == true) {
property.setApproved(false);
data = gson.toJson("False");
} else {
property.setApproved(true);
data = gson.toJson("True");
}
propertyDAO.update(property);
return data;
}
```

if you know about this problem please share answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` reference like below :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.decision').click(function(e) {
$.ajax({

type : 'POST',
dataType : 'json',
url : '/RealEstate/ChangeStatus.html',
data : ({

pid :$(this).siblings('.pid').val()
}),
success : function(response) {
alert(response);
$(this).html(response);
^------^ // here use this instead of .decision selector
/* $('.decision').text(response); */
},
error : function() {
alert('Error while request..');
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: firstly thanks for your answer but this code is note working properly because the status is not change when clicked but it's change when refreshing the page

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.decision').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'json',
       url : '/RealEstate/ChangeStatus.html',
       data : ({ pid :$(this).siblings('.pid').val() }),
    })
    .done(function(response) {
           alert(response);
           $(this).text(response);
       })
    .fail(function() {
          alert('Error while request..');
       });
    });
});
</script>
```